# Using Jquery to toggle nested table

Tags: jquery

In a .NET MVC project, a search generates a table with header and an unknown number of rows. Each of these rows in turn will hide a nested table, with header and an unknown number of rows. I want the nested tables to expand upon clicking the corresponding row.

So far, I've got this:

```
<script>
    $('div.ordergrid table.orders tbody tr.row td').click(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().parent().children('tr.rowdetail').toggle();
    }
)
</script>

<div id="ordergrid">

    <table id="orders">
        <thead>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th>Foo</th>
            <th colspan="3">Foo</th>
            <th>Foo</th>
        </thead>
    @foreach (var mo in Model)
    {
        <tbody>
            <tr class="row">
                <td>Bar</td>
                <td>Bar</td>
                <td>Bar</td>
                <td>Bar</td>
                <td colspan="3">Bar</td>
                <td>Bar</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rowdetail">
                <td colspan="8">
                    <table>
                        <thead>
                            <th>Baz</th>
                            <th>Baz</th>
                            <th>Baz</th>
                            <th>Baz</th>
                            <th>Baz</th>
                            <th>Baz</th>
                            <th>Baz</th>
                            <th>Baz</th>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td>1</td>
                                <td>2</td>
                                <td>3</td>
                                <td>4</td>
                                <td>5</td>
                                <td>6</td>
                                <td>7</td>
                                <td>8</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
    }

    </table>
</div>
```

(The nested tbody will later be replaced with another foreach.)

Currently, nothing happens upon clicking. The click event does not seem to "stick" to the intended control.

Oh, and the `.parent().parent()` thing looks a bit silly, but I was unsure of how to correctly select with `.parents()`.

Comment: Do you see an error? What happens if you just console.log something on the click event? If that works, try logging what `.parent().parent().children('tr.rowdetail')` returns. Does it return any/the correct elements? Also, do the elements exist in the DOM when you bind the click element to them? If not, have a look into using https://api.jquery.com/on/ instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the HTML given, you could do it like this

```
$('.row').click(function () {
    $(this).next('tr').toggle();
});
```

When a row with `class="row"` is clicked, it'll get the next row (which'll be the hidden one if your structure is correct) and toggle its visibility.

Or you could use slightly more specific selectors,

```
$('tr.row').click(function () {
    $(this).next('tr.rowdetail').toggle();
});
```

which would get the next element with class `rowdetail` and toggle it's visibility. In the example structure given, both would do the same thing, but being specific with your selectors generally leads to less unpredictable results. How specific you are in this instance really depends on what the rest of your page's content looks like.

Comment: Much like with Wilmer's suggestion, both of these leads to the "Bar" row getting duplicated upon getting clicked, while the nested tables always show. So I guess something's wrong in the HTML?

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson Sounds like it. Something else I noticed, `<tbody>` & `</tbody>` tags should be outside for foreach loop (as you only want one tbody for your table)

Comment: Nevermind that comment, I must have been confused. Your solution worked, I just thought the sub tables would be collapsed by default :)

Comment: @ChristoferOlsson ah, if you want them collapsed by default, you just need a css rule `.rowdetail{display:none;}`

Comment: thanks, I tried to set it on the table at first. But realize that was wrong aws it's the tr that's getting toggled.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector seems to be wrong you are using class selectors instead of id selectors, need to use a "#". Also you can select the adjacent tr using the next() function.

```
$('div#ordergrid table#orders tbody tr.row td').click(
    function () {
        $(this).parent().next('tr.rowdetail').toggle();
    }
);
```

Comment: Please can you expand on this: Rather than just giving code, explain what it's doing and why it solves the problem!

Comment: Ah, yes. I did totally mix up classes and ids. This suggestion toggles *something*, but it makes the outer tr ("Bar") toggle a copy of itself, while the inner table remains expanded.

Comment: Oh wait, it does not duplicate itself, but rather it just fetches the next order.

Comment: It shows/hides the next tr which contains the table isn't that expected?

Comment: You will have to excuse my stupidity, but you are entirely correct. I just need to have them collapsed by default, and that's it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
$('div.ordergrid table.orders tr.row > td').click(function () {
    $(this).closest('tr.row').next('tr.rowdetail').toggle();
})
```

You need to toggle the `.rowdetails` row which is next to the clicked `.row` row